# How do I bind to a custom property on a ContentControl when using Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a usercontrol that exposes a few dependency properties. If I was to use this user control directly I'd just set a binding directly in the view for the property, ex:

```
<uc:MyControl MyCustomProperty="{Binding SomeOtherProperty}" />
```

Since I'm using Caliburn Micro and MVVM, it seems the preferred way is to create a property on the "parent" viewmodel of type MyControlViewModel then place a ContentControl in the view. That is supposed to create the ViewModel associated with the user control "MyControl" (instead of sticking all the code in the "codebehind" of my user control), then set the datacontext so it's bound together.

So the ViewModel of the "parent" screen would look like this:

```
public MyControlViewModel MyControl { get; set; }
// MyControlViewModel gets either passed in via contructor or instanciated in the contructor
```

And the view of the parent screen would have this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyControl" />
```

That works great. Caliburn renders the control into the ContentControl and it's bound to the MyControlViewModel as expected.

My question is - how do I bind MyCustomProperty at this point? ContentControl doesn't expose MyCustomProperty. Is there some syntax that I can use here where I can set this binding up?

Comment: I think exactly what you are trying to do was lost in the simplification, but let me say this: Having custom controls (descendants of Control/FrameworkElement) is still a completely normal part of Caliburn and MVVM. When your view needs advanced view-only logic (e.g. advanced animations or custom scrolling behavior), create a custom control. Then that custom control can be part of a view's xaml. This is still MVVM and view-model first. You construct a view model and Caliburn's ViewLocator locates the associated view (which can contain a custom control, just like it can contain a Button).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to hopefully clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Are you trying to use Caliburn in a view-first way? Although it does support that, it is recommended to use it in a viewmodel-first way. If you go viewmodel-first (recommended), then your parent view model will pass whatever data into the child view model that it needs. Your view doesn't have to worry about binding at a different level. In MVVM, all the logic and dependencies should be declared in the view model layer, the view is just a dumb presentation layer on top.